# Automation of data download using Rblpapi

Tags: r, finance, bloomberg

I am downloading data (Bid and Ask price) from Bloomberg using R for the specific duration 15:15 to 15:16 Indian Standard Time. Please find the code. Right now I am running the script everyday by manually changing the date everyday. I would like to automate this stuff. I would like to run the script without making changes.

```
library('Rblpapi')
con = blpConnect()

Function_getTick<-function(Bloomberg_Instrument_Name)
{

    local.times    <- as.POSIXct(c("2016-07-05 15:15:00", "2016-07-05 15:16:00"), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    temp_dataframe <- getTicks(Bloomberg_Instrument_Name, eventType = "BID",
                               startTime = local.times[1], endTime = local.times[2],
                               verbose = FALSE)
    temp_dataframe2 <- getTicks(Bloomberg_Instrument_Name, eventType = "ASK",
                                startTime = local.times[1], endTime = local.times[2],
                                verbose = FALSE)
}
```

Comment: You just replace the `local.times <-` line with `local.times    <- as.POSIXct(paste(Sys.Date(), c("15:15:00","15:16:00")), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")` ?  This would use the current date.